# Failed to Sync Gradle, could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0

Tags: android, gradle, butterknife

Installing Butter Knife dependencies generates this error

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0.
Required by:
    Butter:app:unspecified
    Butter:app:unspecified > com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1
    Butter:app:unspecified > com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1 > com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.0.1

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

I have installed support library but it still I get this error. Here is how Gradle dependencies look like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'

}
```

I have also added plugin `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` and repositories

```
jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you definitely installed that version of the annotations lib?

Comment: You should be able to use annotations anyway thanks to the v7 dependency, which (as far as I remember) has a inner dependency to annotations. Remove the line so you'll keep both libraries in sync.

Comment: visit this : https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Google Repository in SDK Manager[image]

Comment: I am on revision 25 but still the problem persist. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Update Android Support Repository.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your build.gradle file :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be replacing "provided" by "compileOnly" in build.gradle (Module: app).